# Determine if I called a method in a object context

Tags: php, class, magic-methods

For example this class:

```
class A{

  public function __call($func, $args){
    if($func == 'something')
      call_user_func_array($this->_some_magic, $args);
  }

  public function _some_magic(){
    ...
  }

  public static function something(){
    ...
  }

}
```

Now if I call $a::something() I want the something() method to run (like now).

But if I call $a->something() I want to trigger that undefined method stuff so I can do my magic, not something()...

Is there any way I can detect the way the method was called and execute the method I desire?

ps: I know I could do this using __callstatic and renaming something to something else, but I was wondering if there's a better solution in which I can keep the current static method name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See 
 - __call http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call 
 - __callStatic http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic

Or are you talking about determining whether its an external call e.g.:

```
$a = new A();
$a->doSomething();
```

vs

```
class A {
    public function doSomething() {}
    public function callDoSomething() { $this->doSomething(); }
}
```

If its the later case then I'd suggest simply making you internal class calls call another method which the external method call also routes to, e.g.:

```
class A {
    public function doSomething() { $this->_doSomething(); }
    public function callDoSomething() { $this->_doSomething(); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using php 5.3.0 and higher you can use [`callStatic`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) magic method, if you're using lower version or you want it to be compatible, I'm afraid you will need to use hack like this:

```
static protected $calledStatic = false;

public function __call( $func, $args){
  if( self::$calledStatic){
     ...
     self::$calledStatic = false;
  }
}

public static function something(){
  self::$calledStatic = true;
}
```